# Get values outside of jsonArray for loop

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, android-volley

I'm working on a grocery app for my project and I got this JSON Array

```
[
    {   
        "msg":"success",
        "id":"1904",
        "firstname":"john",
        "lastname":"doe",
        "email":"johndoe@gmail.com",
        "mobile":"10111213",
        "appapikey ":"aba27d8447acd61152ad716696465c27"
    }
]
```

And I'm using `Volley` StringRequest

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {

  var jsonArrayInfo = JSONArray(it)

  for(i in 0 until(jsonArrayInfo.length())) {

     var userInfo = jsonArrayInfo.getJSONObject(i)

     var fName = userInfo.getString("firstname")
     var lName = userInfo.getString("lastname")
     var eMail = userInfo.getString("email")
     var moBile = userInfo.getString("mobile")
     var apiKey = userInfo.getString("appapikey ")

     Toast.makeText(view.context, "Welcome $apiKey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}

var i = Intent(view.context, MainActivity::class.java)
//I want to bring the values out here
//to use them in another class with putExtra()
startActivity(i)
...
...
```

Is there a way I can get those items (id, firstname, lastname, email,...) outside of the `for` loop to to putExtra() to use them in another activity?

Thank you!

Comment: convert your response to POJO using gson library https://github.com/google/gson and pass the POJO to other activity using intent, serilization

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading about it and it looks something I would want to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variables out of the loop then modify them inside the loop. Here is your code with implementations of my answer.

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {

var jsonArrayInfo = JSONArray(it)
var fName = ""
var lName = ""
var eMail = ""
var moBile = ""
var apiKey = ""

for(i in 0 until(jsonArrayInfo.length())) {

    var userInfo = jsonArrayInfo.getJSONObject(i)

    fName = userInfo.getString("firstname")
    lName = userInfo.getString("lastname")
    eMail = userInfo.getString("email")
    moBile = userInfo.getString("mobile")
    apiKey = userInfo.getString("appapikey ")

    Toast.makeText(view.context, "Welcome $apiKey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that before but didn't work. 
But I think it's just me making mistakes somewhere. Won't hurt to try again!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the JSON Array to an ArrayList of [Bundles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) and then use `putParcelableArrayListExtra`.

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {

  var jsonArrayInfo = JSONArray(it)

  val bundles = ArrayList<Bundle>()

  for(i in 0 until(jsonArrayInfo.length())) {

     var userInfo = jsonArrayInfo.getJSONObject(i)
     val bundle = Bundle()

     bundle.putCharSequence(userInfo.getString("firstname"))
     bundle.putCharSequence(userInfo.getString("lastname"))
     bundle.putCharSequence(userInfo.getString("email"))
     bundle.putCharSequence(userInfo.getString("mobile"))
     bundle.putCharSequence(userInfo.getString("appapikey "))

     bundles.add(bundle)
  }

  var i = Intent(view.context, MainActivity::class.java)
  i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", bundles)
  startActivity(i)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. I think I can initialize the variables outside but that a bit...redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayLists=new ArrayList<>();
var jsonArrayInfo = JSONArray(it)

  for(i in 0 until(jsonArrayInfo.length())) {
 ArrayList arr= new ArrayList();
 var userInfo = jsonArrayInfo.getJSONObject(i)

 var fName = userInfo.getString("firstname")
 var lName = userInfo.getString("lastname")
 var eMail = userInfo.getString("email")
 var moBile = userInfo.getString("mobile")
 var apiKey = userInfo.getString("appapikey ")
 arr.add(fName);
 arr.add(lName);
 arr.add(eMail);
 arr.add(moBile);
 arr.add(apiKey);
 arrayLists.add(arr);
 Toast.makeText(view.context, "Welcome $apiKey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

 }
//to send another Activity
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
startActivity(i)

//receive Another Activity
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>)) 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Comment: Thank you! It's another way to do the job!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to pass the response string as a stringExtra of the Intent and deserialize it in the other Activity

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {

var i = Intent(view.context, MainActivity::class.java)
i.putExtra("response", it.toString())
startActivity(i)
```

In **MainActivity**

```
  val res = intent.getStringExtra("response")
  var jsonArrayInfo = JSONArray(res)

  for(i in 0 until(jsonArrayInfo.length())) {

     var userInfo = jsonArrayInfo.getJSONObject(i)

     var fName = userInfo.getString("firstname")
     var lName = userInfo.getString("lastname")
     var eMail = userInfo.getString("email")
     var moBile = userInfo.getString("mobile")
     var apiKey = userInfo.getString("appapikey ")

     Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome $apiKey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of this! I'm going to try it out now